# Are widget(), update() and form() pre-created functions in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

On the [Wordpress Codex page for 'register widget'](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_widget) there is basic example code given for registering a widget via your plugin:-

```
class MyNewWidget extends WP_Widget {

    function __construct() {
        // Instantiate the parent object
        parent::__construct( false, 'My New Widget Title' );
    }

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        // Widget output
    }

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        // Save widget options
    }

    function form( $instance ) {
        // Output admin widget options form
    }
}

function myplugin_register_widgets() {
    register_widget( 'MyNewWidget' );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'myplugin_register_widgets' );
```

In this code, as you can see the three functions I mentioned are provided. I want to know if I can change their names or are they pre-created Wordpress functions?

Comment: No, you can not change their names. Your own widget class must provides these methods by exactly those names, because they will be called later on when the widget is shown/updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can name your members in MyNewWidget whatever you like, but the point of extending WP_Widget is that WP_Widget's methods are all available to MyNewWidget but you can override them by writing a method of the same name. [This may help explain](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php).